# CanCanCan Ability test doesn't pass but it works fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cancancan

I have the following ability defined in my Ability.rb:

```
if user.role? :chief
   can [:action1, :action2], Request, user: {id: user.subordinate_ids}
end
```

And in my ability tests I have the following:

```
subject{ Ability.new(user) }
let(:user) { create(:chief_user) }
let(:subordinate) { create(:user, boss: user) }

it { is_expected.to be_able_to([:action1, :action2], Request.new(user: subordinate)) }
```

The ability works as expected while making manual tests, but I can't make this test work. I've tried Request.create with the appropiate parameters, but I still get the same result.

I've done some debugging and the corresponding associations are in order (the chief has subordinates and the requests belong to a subordinate so the actual test is that a chief can only action1, action2 the requests of his subordinates).

I'm using CanCanCan and RSpec for my tests.

Any insights on how to make this test work?

Comment: Since you're using the let syntax you might need to ensure the object are persisted before calling tests on them

Comment: Hello, Dave, thanks for your answer. What do you mean by ensuring the objects persist? I've made some debugging by putting puts within the it and everything prints as it should

Answer (score 0):

rspec's let syntax is basically using a Proc (lazy loading) so until you call it it doesn't actually get persisted. when you call it in a spec sometimes you're testing something that hasn't been persisted yet.

You could check this by adding a before block

```
subject{ Ability.new(user) }
let(:user) { create(:chief_user) }
let(:subordinate) { create(:user, boss: user) }

it { is_expected.to be_able_to([:action1, :action2], Request.new(user: subordinate)) }
```

Try adding the before line below

```
subject{ Ability.new(user) }
let(:user) { create(:chief_user) }
let(:subordinate) { create(:user, boss: user) }

# new line to ensure object exists before test run
before {expect(subordinate).to eq subordinate}

it { is_expected.to be_able_to([:action1, :action2], Request.new(user: subordinate)) }
```

kind of frustrating IMO but I've run up against this before

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by doing this:

```
subject{ Ability.new(user) }
let!(:user) { create(:chief_user) }
let!(:subordinate) { create(:user, boss: user) }
[:action1, :action2].each do |action|
    it { is_expected.to be_able_to(action, Request.new(user: subordinate)}
end
```

It didn't work by doing it together.